# Extract only date from datetime for calculating total time in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have date time data in database and from that im calculating total hours only taking the date not the timing.
im using strtotime for that calculations. For ex:

```
$LastDate = '2016-04-27 17:27:28';
$endDate = strtotime($LastDate); // 1461770848

$LastDate = '2016-04-27';
$endDate = strtotime($LastDate); // 1461708000
```

I want this second value only.
So i want to extract the date from the $LastDate .

```
 ///////////Getting data from Employee Outstation(Travel) details from database/////////////
   $employeeTravel = new EmployeeTravelRecord();     

   $TravelEntryList = $employeeTravel->Find("employee = 2 and (date(travel_date) <= ? and ? <=  date(return_date))",array($req['date_end'],$req['date_start']));

            $startdate = $req['date_start'];
            $enddate = $req['date_end'];
            foreach($TravelEntryList as $Travelentry){

                    $key = $Travelentry->employee;

                    if($startdate >= $Travelentry->travel_date)
                    {
                        $firstdate = $startdate;
                    }
                    else
                        $firstdate = $Travelentry->travel_date;

                    if($enddate <= $Travelentry->return_date )
                    {
                        $lastdate = $enddate;
                    }
                    else
                        $lastdate = $Travelentry->return_date;

                    $holidays = $this->getholidays($firstdate,$lastdate);

                    $totalhours = $this->getWorkingDays($firstdate,$lastdate,$holidays);                    
                    $amount = $totalhours;  
    }

    private function getWorkingDays($FirstDate,$LastDate,$holidays){        

        $endDate = strtotime($LastDate); //Here i want to give only date not the time
        $startDate = strtotime($FirstDate); 

        $days = ($endDate - $startDate) / 86400 + 1;

        $no_full_weeks = floor($days / 7);
        $no_remaining_days = fmod($days, 7);    
    //Im doing even and odd saturday calculations....finally...

    $workinghours = $workingDays*9 +  $no_saturdays*7;  
        return $workinghours;
    }
```

Comment: use `date()` function then use `strtotime()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

such expression gives you desired result

```
echo strtotime('midnight', strtotime('2016-04-27 22:11')); // 1461715200
echo strtotime('2016-04-27'); // 1461715200
```